# Improving SQL Server performance for inserting bigdata

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a process of inserting around 1 billion records into a SQL Server table. The process is lengthy and I am trying to improve it.

Therefore I have done these:

- Removed all indexes and primary key from inserted table
- Removed all select/update checks before insert
- Checked SQL Server memory max, it seems already big enough

[image]

I wonder if limiting log file size would help in improving SQL Server performance? If so, how can I do that?

Is there any other things I can do to improve the insert process?

**Edit**

SQL Server version : 15.0.2000.5

Data loading through .Net application where I process data and send it to a stored procedure that has insert statement only (all on the same PC there is no network i.e. SQL server and .Net app both on the same machine)

Currently around 20 million records has been inserted in 50 minutes

Server specs : 
[image]

Recovery Mode = Full

I removed all indexes clustered and non-clustered

Comment: What version of SQL Server? How are you loading the data?  How fast is the load currently? What are the server specs? Is the database in SIMPLE recovery mode?  Are you loading a clustered columnstore table?  Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-data-loading-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have edited my post with the info you asked

Comment: You're getting more than 6500 records per second. How fast (terms of records per second) do you think you ought to be able to go?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have 100 multi thread  .net functions inserting to the table with 100 connections to the DB, the bottleneck is from SQL Server

Comment: Does the stored procedure insert one row at a time?  Are you batching inserts into Transactions?  Have you considered using SqlBulkCopy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1?

Comment: 16GB for a database server is *not* a lot of data. The settings you posted are irrelevant as the server simply doesn't have that much data. That said, *how* you insert the data is *far more important* than those settings. Do you use BULK INSERT? SqlBulkCopy? Or inserting rows one by one with an ORM?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, I insert 1 record at the time. did not think of bulk insert and not sure how to do it

Comment: @asmgx `I have 100 multi thread .net functions inserting to the table with 100 connections`  there's your problem then. You created a 100-way locking nightmare that results in *far more* than 100 times worse performance

Comment: `I insert 1 record at the time.` adding that, just makes this the slowest way to insert possible. Use only *one* thread, *one* connection and SqlBulkCopy to insert the data. After all, you only have one set of disks, one network card so what's the point of using *100* connections?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have done some test on that, it is not 100 times faster than a single thread but it is much faster than a single thread

Comment: No it's not, unless the code and tests are bad. Use SqlBulkCopy and insert the data as a stream. Or use SSIS to insert the data. Or BULK INSERT. Only if that's not fast enough try with 2 connections etc

Comment: There's no ifs and buts about this. You have only so much IO and network bandwidth, you **DON'T** want to waste it in synchronisation across 100 conflicting connections

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what I am doing is reading XML then insert it 1 record at the time, is there a way to insert XML files directly to table?

Comment: Worse and worse, and what you posted in the question has no effect on performance any more. Post your code. Quite likely, XML parsing causes a far greater delay than inserting into SQL and what you measured is improvement in XML parsing, not SQL insertion

Comment: There are ways to [bulk import large XML documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) but this may not be good enough for your data and schema. Post a sample of the data and your code at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I insert 1 record at the time.

That's not going to be super-fast.  Send multiple rows to SQL Server in each command.  The fastest way is typically [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), and you probably don't need to do anything in parallel. Also using Table-Valued Parameters or JSON to send multiple rows at once will both be much faster than what you are doing.

> what I am doing is reading XML then insert it 1

You can send the whole XML doc to SQL Server and shred it with xml [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) or [openxml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Or you can use an XMLReader and pipe the rows into SqlBulkCopy by implemnting a custom IDataReader that reads from the XML stream.

Comment: The 100 concurrent connections are far, far worse for performance. Theoretically, this 100-way block can lead to 100! worse performance

Comment: what I am doing is reading XML then insert it 1 record at the time, is there a way to insert XML files directly to table?

Comment: If the doc is huge it will be faster to break it up or stream it with SqlBulkCopy.